# gchords, flush left chords

Tags: alignment

How can I modify the following code in order to make the row of chords flush left?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{gchords}

\begin{document}

\chords{
\chord{}{f1p1,f1p1,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}
\chord{}{n,n,f1p1,f1p1,f2p2,f3p2}{}
}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gchords` package defines `\chords` to be `$$\hbox{#1}$$` which seems an odd choice, since the content isn't math. So probably the best solution is to redefine `\chords` to remove the `$$`: (I'm using the `geometry` package here just to show the alignment.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{gchords}
\renewcommand\chords[1]{\hbox{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chords{
\chord{}{f1p1,f1p1,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}
\chord{}{n,n,f1p1,f1p1,f2p2,f3p2}{}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]